# Graphics: Painting rectangle from jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, graphics

I have a jagged array of rectangles like so (inside of Form1_Paint):

```
Rectangle[][] r = new Rectangle[3][];
```

When I try to paint rectangles from the array, for example

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangles(b, r[0][i]);
```

Where "i" is a variable in a for loop, it gives the error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangles(System.Drawing.Brush,
>   System.Drawing.Rectangle[])` has some invalid arguments

Is there any way to use a jagged array, or do I have to break it into individual 1d arrays for the FillRectangles and DrawRectangles method? I am trying to paint the jagged array of rectangles row by row instead of all at once.

Comment: You should use `RectangleF` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To paint single rectangles one at a time in an array, the method FillRectangle() can be used instead of FillRectangles(). Therefore, FillRectangles(r[0][i]) works.